# String.Format an integer to use a thousands separator without decimal places or leading 0 for small integers

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Silly question, I want to format an integer so that it appears with the 1000's separator (,), but also without decimal places and without a leading 0.

My attempts so far have been:

```
String.Format("{0} {1}", 5, 5000);            // 5 5000
String.Format("{0:n} {1:n}", 5, 5000);        // 5.00 5,000.00
String.Format("{0:0,0} {1:0,0}", 5, 5000);    // 05 5,000
```

The output I'm after is:

```
5 5,000
```

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: For those looking up this answer: Keep in mind that other cultures may return a dot (.) for thousand separators. So make sure where you're gonna use this string and parse it correctly then.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
String.Format("{0:#,0} {1:#,0}", 5, 5000); // 5 5,000
```

Comment: System.String.Format("Bla: {0:#,##0;(- #,##0)}", 803000000.656)

Comment: if without rounding: System.String.Format("Bla: {0:#,##0;(- #,##0)}", Floor(803000000.456))

Answer (score 48):

Try this:-

```
String.Format("{0:n0}",5000) // 5,000
String.Format("{0:n0}",5) // 5
String.Format("{0:n0}",0) // 0
```

Comment: Is this one cultured? i.e., will use the correct thousands separator?

Comment: Yes, If u have not provided the FormatProvider then String.Format uses the current culture info. So if u have changed the digit grouping symbol(thousand separator) from , to - then result will be 5-000 instead of 5,000

Comment: This is by far the best solution here since it takes in account the user culture! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 26):

```
String.Format("{0:#,0} {1:#,0}", 5, 5000); // "5 5,000"
```

- `0` in a format string means put the digit that belongs here, or else a [leading/trailing] zero [to make things align, etc.]. EDIT: You'll definitely want one as the last digit in the pattern, or a zero value will be rendered as an empty String
- `#` means don't put anything into the output unless there's a significant digit here.

EDIT (thanks @eulerfx):

- the last portion needs to be a `0` rather than a `#` (as I initially had it) as a value of zero would otherwise be rendered as a zero-length string.

Comment: `#` doesn't really put a space anywhere does it? I thought it just did nothing if there isn't a digit to place there...

Comment: This returns an empty string when the number is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
String.Format("{0:#,#}", 4000);
```

Comment: See @eulerfx's comment re my answer

Answer (score 1):

With the introduction [String interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/exploration/interpolated-strings) in C# 6.0, there is a better/nicer way to work with strings using [`$`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)  and string formatting using [`{variable/value[,alignment][:formatString]}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation?source=recommendations).

```
$"{5:#,0} {5000:#,0}"; // 5 5,000
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This also works:

40000.ToString("#,#")