# Print integer with comma as thousands separator (1234567 to "1,234,567")

Tags: c#

I have an integer that needs to be converted to a string with thousands separated by comma. I tried

```
string.Format("{0:n}", 999999)
```

However, the output I get is "999,999.00". I don't want the ".00" part to appear.

Comment: Does it need to be comma separated or just thousands separated?  Not every country in the world uses comma as a thousands separator.

Comment: Note that the term "comma separated value" is commonly the name of a file format (.CSV), so it can be confusing if you try to use it to describe a number format with thousands separators.

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** This question has already been answered before: [String.Format an integer to use 1000's separator without decimal places or leading 0 for small integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1666346/240733).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could specify 0 as the precision:

```
string x = string.Format("{0:n0}", 999999);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

or more simply if you don't really need it within a bigger format string:

```
string x = 999999.ToString("n0");
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Note that this will use the default "thousand separator" for the current culture. If you want to force it to use commas, you should probably specify the culture explicitly:

```
string x = 999999.ToString("n0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

I wouldn't personally describe this as "comma-separated" by the way - that's usually used to describe a format which combines multiple different values. I'd just talk about this "including comma as a thousand separator".

Comment: does the 0 after `n` just indicate 0 decimal places?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: In this case, yes. In general it's the "precision specifier" - for the "n" format that means the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 999999;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("###,###"));
```

Comment: If you want custom separator it will not work. So it can be not comma (depending on your current locale).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
decimal Rupees = 999999999900;
string numberString = Rupees.ToString("00,00,000",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN"));
Response.Write(numberString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is most universal and correct:

```
const int value = 1234567890;

        NumberFormatInfo format = new NumberFormatInfo();
        format.NumberDecimalDigits = 0; // Int32 should not contain decimals.
        format.NumberGroupSeparator = "'"; // Use any separator string here, for example comman as you requested.
        format.NumberGroupSizes = new[] { 3 }; // Theoretically can be commented, but use it to specify number of digits in group directly.

        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("N", format));
```