# Format number with comma separator for thousands using C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String.Format an integer to use 1000's separator without decimal places or leading 0 for small integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666346/string-format-an-integer-to-use-1000s-separator-without-decimal-places-or-leadin)

The blog post

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

(in the Custom number formatting section) shows that using the format {0:0,0}, a number like 1500 will be formatted as **1,500** which is good.  But I don't understand why 0 is formatted as **00**

Do I need to handle the case of 0 separately which doesn't seem to be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "F0", which is "fixed number with 0 decimal places". It give you a thousands separator when you results go over 1,000.