# How to add thousands separator in highcharts tool tip text box

Tags: c#, highcharts, number-formatting

I am trying to format a number in a highcharts tool tip text box. The number looks like this #######.## and I want #,###,###.## how can I do this? The code I have now is:

```
PointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: {point.y:.2f}</b>"
```

I have tried:

```
PointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: {point.y:.2n}</b>"
```

to format it as a number, but this does not work. I am not so great with my number formats.

Comment: duplicit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1666378/4640779

Comment: I saw that already, "PointFormat = "<b>{series.name}: {point.y:#,0}</b>"  does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use thousand separator in lang

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.setOptions({

    lang: {
      decimalPoint: '.',
      thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

and in tooltip- formatter use like

```
  {point.y:,.2f}
```

Comment: I gave the following a try, but it's not doing anything. The format still remains...   .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions{ Lang = new DotNet.Highcharts.Helpers.Lang { ThousandsSep = ","} })

Comment: Actually, I take that back, I just had to go and remove the :.2f and now it works! the .2f was undoing the ThousandsSep, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
plotOptions:{
dataLabels:{
format: {point.y: ,.1f}
}
}
```

like this it wil also work for datalabels too.

and same goes for tooltip like @Nishith mentioned