# String.Format() convert decimal? to ###,###,###.00 format

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert decimal? price to formatted price. I need such price format:
222,777,333.00 
This is my code: `String.Format(item.SalePrice.ToString(), "###,###,###.00")`.
Result: 99999.000000
Help, please.

Comment: Check this might help u http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/format-a-string-as-currency-in-c/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String.Format an integer to use a thousands separator without decimal places or leading 0 for small integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666346/string-format-an-integer-to-use-a-thousands-separator-without-decimal-places-or)

Comment: Does the output need to be culture-dependent or culture-agnostic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should do it:  
`item.SalePrice.ToString("N2");`

Comment: Be aware, your code uses `CurrentCulture` settings _by default_ and this _might_ generate different thousand and decimal separators if you don't specify it.

Answer (score 2):

Try `item.SalePrice.ToString("###,###,###.00");`

It works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
item.SalePrice.ToString("N");
```

Check out [this msdn article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx) for more options in regards to `Decimal.ToString()`.

Comment: Be aware, your code uses `CurrentCulture` settings _by default_ and this _might_ generate different thousand and decimal separators if you don't specify it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [The numeric (`"N"`) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) in a `2` precision specifier with a culture that has `,` as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx) and `.` as a [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx)) is the best way in your case.

```
item.SalePrice.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

If you don't specify *any* culture, this method uses `CurrentCulture` by default and you *might* get different representation if your `CurrentCulture` has different specifiers for these properties.